# Core Data en iOS9 e iOS10 simultaneamente

Tags: xcode, app

Buenas tardes,

Tengo una pregunta sobre Swift(y Xcode), relacionada con el Core Data. El problema que tengo es que estoy haciendo una app con Swift 3 en Xcode 8, y esta en principio da soporte a iOS9 e iOS10 pero al instanciar el appDelegate y el Context (para luego poder sacar (o meter) de cada Entity lo que necesito), en iOS9 me es imposible. 
He pensado que lo mejor es hacer algo como:

```
#if avaliable(iOS10,*)
{
     //CodigoParaiOS10
} else
{
    //CodigoParaiOS9
}
```

El problema que veo con esta solución es que para iOS9 no sé que utilizar para conseguir la variable context. He visto códigos en StackOverflow pero nada me funciona. También he intentado buscar tutoriales de iOS9, pero como están en Swift 2 o 2.3, y hay muchas funciones que han cambiado o eliminado, y por tanto tampoco me funciona.

¿Alguna otra idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta la he publicado en este link. Es el link de una pregunta idéntica.

[CoreData para iOS9 y iOS10 simultáneamente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651239/ios-9-and-ios-10-coredata-simultaneously/44154265#44154265)

En mi repuesta está todo el código de:

**AppDelegate.swift**

**MasterViewController.swift**

**DetailViewController.swift**

A partir de estos códigos se puede desarrollar la aplicación que sea y que utilice CoreData para iOS9 e iOS10 simultáneamente.

Se trata del template original Master-Detail Application de Apple actualizado con Xcode 8.2.1 (el último hasta la fecha), utilizando lenguaje Swift 3.

Comment: El enlace que has publicado se corresponde con la versión inglesa de StackOverflow. Dado que este portal es para contenido exclusivamente en español te sugiero traducir la respuesta para que esta respuesta en concreto pueda ser tan util como la que se encuentra en la versión inglesa.